# Flask, flask-jwt-extended - trying to custom handle Unauthorized error

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-jwt-extended

I am building a flask webapp and I am trying to return custom error message in case of 401 error which is raised when auth header is missing. For Authentication I use Flask-Jwt-Extended. I want to overwrite `expired_token_loader(callback)` to return 401 error and then catch it using @app.errohandler(401) and redirect to login.
So far I have done this:

```
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def unauthorized_callback(callback):
    # Missing auth header
    # abort(401)
    return make_response("", 401)

@app.errorhandler(401)
def unauthorized(e):
    return "Custom 401 Error", 401
```

Found out in official Flask-JWT-Extended documentation that ***the function decorated with @jwt.unauthorized_loader must return a Flask Response.*** 
So when I try to `abort(401)` as it is shown above and not return anything from `unaturhorized_callback()` it shows `werkzeug.exceptions.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: ...` 
 
And when I `return make_response("", 401)` it shows this, that means that the error handler did not handle the error: 
[image]


**EDIT:** I am trying to redirect on trigger of the @jwt.unauthorized_loader so I wanted to throw an 401 error and then catch it with for example @app.errorhandler(401) and redirect. 
 I am doing this because I am also building a **mobile app** where I am catching 401 error and when I redirect inside the `@jwt.unauthorized_loader` it is always error 302, otherwise the redirect won't work. So I cannot do `make_response(redirect("/login"), 401)`. **So my goal is to throw 401 error and then handle it different ways in web app and mobile app**. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what I wanted but in the end it did what I need. Insted of redirecting with custom http response code I did `render_template` with 401 code as shown below:

```
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def unauthorized_callback(callback):
    # Missing auth header
    flash("Missing auth header please login")
    return make_response(render_template("login.html"), 401)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this isn't working is because the callback method for `@jwt.unauthorized_loader` is already called in the context of an `@app.errorhandler`, and any exception raised in an errorhandler will not cause trigger other errorhandlers.

Instead of trying to handle this with aborts and exceptional control flow, why not just use a helper method to make your custom response and use it in both places?

```py
def unauthorized_response():
    return make_response("Custom 401 Error", 401)

@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def unauthorized_callback(callback):
    return unauthorized_response()

@app.errorhandler(401)
def unauthorized(e):
    return unauthorized_response()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I am trying to redirect on trigger of the `@jwt.unauthorized_loader` so I wanted to throw an 401 error and then catch it with for example `@app.errorhandler(401)` and redirect. I am doing this because I am also building a **mobile app** where I am catching 401 error and when I redirect inside the `@jwt.unauthorized_loader` it is always error 302, otherwise the redirect won't work. So I cannot do  `make_response(redirect("/login"), 401)`.  **So my goal is to throw 401 error and then handle it different ways in web app and mobile app**. **Thanks for you help**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using flask_restful, you can define an errors dictionary when initializing your API to map specific exceptions:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_jwt_extended.exceptions import NoAuthorizationError
from jwt.exceptions import ExpiredSignatureError

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, errors={
    'NoAuthorizationError': {
        'message': "Missing Authorization Header",
        'status': 401,
    },
    'ExpiredSignatureError': {
        'message': "Token has expired",
        'status': 401,
    },
})
jwt = JWTManager(app)

# Continue setting up routes and jwt protected endpoints
```